# Magento 2 - Checkout Page New Block Add & Move

Tags: magento, magento2

I added a new block to the checkout page, but I couldn't move it above the "Shipping Address" text.
What I want to do is make the "Custom CheckoutConfig Data:" block appear above the "Shipping address" block
I added the checkout_index_index.xml file.

Can anyone with experience help?

Click [here image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv9DJ.png)

checkout_index_index.xml

```
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="comments" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_CheckoutConfig/js/view/shipping/comment</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
```

```
item name="before-form" xsi:type="array" /item
```

I tried deleting your attribute, it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please check the template you created and mention it in the **checkout_index_index.xml** file.

Please follow the steps follow:

1: Create JS
2: Create a template
3: Register Form to Checkout Page

<your_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/js/view/custom-checkout-form.js

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form'
], function(Component) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // component initialization logic
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Form submit handler
         *
         * This method can have any name.
         */
        onSubmit: function() {
            // trigger form validation
            this.source.set('params.invalid', false);
            this.source.trigger('customCheckoutForm.data.validate');

            // verify that form data is valid
            if (!this.source.get('params.invalid')) {
                // data is retrieved from data provider by value of the customScope property
                var formData = this.source.get('customCheckoutForm');
                // do something with form data
                console.dir(formData);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

2: <your_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/template/custom-checkout-form.html

```
<div>
<form id="custom-checkout-form" class="form" data-bind="attr: {'data-hasrequired': $t('* Required Fields')}">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend data-bind="i18n: 'Custom Checkout Form'"></legend>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-checkout-form-fields') -->
        <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    </fieldset>
    <button type="reset">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Reset'"></span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: onSubmit" class="action">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Submit'"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

3: <your_module_dir>/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="before-form" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="custom-checkout-form-container" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <!-- Add this item to configure your js file  -->
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName/js/view/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- And this to add your html template  -->
                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">VendorName_ModuleName/custom-checkout-form</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <!-- Here we will add the form fields  -->
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Clear the modification files:

1. Delete all files in the pub/static/frontend and
   var/view_preprocessed directories.
2. Run step-up static command to regenerate it.
3. Reload the pages

Also, if it does not work, you can specify the before-form in your template and link to the layout.

E.g. Create template: <Magento_Checkout_module_dir>/view/frontend/web/template/custom.html

```
getRegion('before-form')
```

Thanks

Comment: Hello,
Thank you very much for your help.
I tried the methods you showed, but it still didn't work.
This time, the template added on the checkout page did not appear at all.

Thank you